# Rewrite rule to simulate page hierarchy results in 404

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

On my WordPress site, I want pages with slugs beginning with `outline-` or `result-` to be accessible by requesting URI's that begin with `outline/` or `result/` instead, as if the pages in question were subpages of a (nonexistent) `outline` or `result` parent page.

For example, when a visitor types in `https://example.com/result/40-A`, they would be shown the page with the slug `result-40-A`, without the visitor's URL bar reflecting any change.

However, this is giving me a 404 page every time I test it.

Here is the code I have added to my theme's `functions.php` file:

```php
/**
 * Rewrites certain page URL's
 */
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(outline|result)/([^/].*)$',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]-$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
});
```

As far as I'm aware, the regular expression and replacement string are both correct. I have been flushing the rewrite rules cache after every experimental change to my code. I have also added the Query Monitor plugin and found that **the rule is matching, but it is being ignored**—possibly because the resultant SQL query isn't fetching the correct page?

Comment: Are you sure a different rule isn't matching it first? Rewrite rules have order/precedence, it's not the rule that matches best that gets used, it's the rule that matches _first_. Try one of the rewrite rule tester plugins, it's likely it isn't matching in the way that you think it is

Comment: The Query Monitor plugin's interface (and the Rewrite Rules Inspector page) lists my rule as first among the matched rules. Plus, even if this weren't the case, I've encountered the exact same problem when lowering the priority number as low as 1.

Comment: a rewrite tester plugin will give much more useful results, showing the explicit order it was used, the values it used, the resulting query string that it used, etc. Query Monitor is not always the best tool for debugging rewrite rules, though it is helpful

Comment: Edited my previous comment. I also have the Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin, which seemingly lists *all* of the rewrite rules in the order they'd be tested. Mine is high enough for me to be reasonably certain that the order isn't the source of the issue here—in fact, the matching rule that "follows through" is among the very last.